# What is meant by Impulse Response

Tags: signal-processing

I have read in all books that:

```
Impulse(n) = 1 when n=0 , 0 otherwise
```

So when we state impulse response of a signal `x(n)`, I do not understand what is its actual meaning -

Does it mean that for n=1,2,3,4... value of:

```
x(n) . Impulse(0)
```

Hence in that case if n >= 0 we would always get the output `y(n)` from `x(n)` as:

```
x(n) . Impulse(0) = x(n) . 1
```

It is a known fact that anything into 1 would result in same.

But in many DSP problems I see that impulse response (`h(n)`) is = `(1/2)n(u-3)` for example. I am not able to understand what then is the function and technical meaning of Impulse Response.

Please correct my understanding on same.

Comment: I think you'd have more luck asking this at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-meant-by-a-systems-impulse-response-and-frequency-response

Comment: Basically what you've called `Impulse(n)` isn't the impulse response but the impulse function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta). The impulse response is the response of a system to the impulse function as an input signal. The ideal impulse function uniformly consists of every possible frequency thus the impulse response (ie the convolution of your system and the impulse function) is a way of testing the full characteristics (full frequency spectrum) of your system. Also worth nothing that convolving an equation with the impulse function (centered at 0) returns your equation unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A system `G` is said linear and time invariant (LTI) if it is linear and its behaviour doe not change with time or in other words:

**Linearity**: `G[k1*i1(t)+k2*i2(t)] = k1*G[i1]+k2*G[i2]`

**Time Invariance**: `y(n-r) = G[i(n-r)]`

where time invariance means that a delay in the input corresponds to a delay in the output and
where `i`'s are input functions and `k`'s are scalars and `y` output function.

Now in general a lot of systems belong to/can be approximated with this class.

The important fact that I think you are looking for is that these systems are completely characterised by their impulse response. The impulse is the function you wrote, in general the impulse response is how your system reacts to this function: you take your system, you feed it with the impulse and you get the impulse response.

Now you keep the impulse response: when your system is fed with another input, you can calculate the new output by performing the convolution in time between the impulse response and your new input.
That is why the system is completely characterized by the impulse response: whatever input function you take, you can calculate the output by convoluting the input with the impulse response.

Another important fact is that if you perform the Fourier Transform of the impulse response you get the behaviour of your system in the frequency domain.

Considering this you can calculate the output also by taking the FT of your input, the FT of the impulse response, multiply them (in the frequency domain) and then perform the inverse Fourier Transform of the result: the result is the output signal of your system.

Answer (score 1):

The impulse response `h` of a **system** *(not of a signal)* is the output `y` of this system when it is excited by an impulse signal `x` (1 at t = 0, 0 otherwise).

Not diving too much in theory and considerations, this response is very important because most linear sytems (filters, etc...) in signal processing can be written in the form of the following convolution:

```
y(n) = sum(h(u) * x(n-u), u=0, u=L-1);
```

--

The response at n=0 of such system when excited by impulse signal is then:

```
y(0) = h(0) * x(0) + h(1) * x(0-1) + ... h(L-1) * x(0-(L-1))
     = h(0) * x(0) + 0 + 0 + ... + 0   => indeed x is zero everywhere except for t = 0
     = h(0)
```

The response at n = 1, is also:

```
y(1) = h(0) * x(1-0) + h(1) * x(1-1) + ... h(L-1) * x(1-(L-1))
     = 0 + h(1) * x(0) + 0 + 0 + ... + 0   => indeed x is zero everywhere except for t = 0
     = h(1)
```

Tadin ... you see that by exciting the system with impulse response you obtain the values for `h`, thus you can fully characterise your system and know how it will react to any other input signal.